# Static Variable to Implement Shared PTR

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I know a common implementation of shared_ptr uses a heap allocated reference count to keep track of how many things are pointing to an object and then calling destruct automatically when this count drops to zero.

This might be a potentially stupid question because I don't understand the object oriented mechanics of C++ very well, but I was wondering if there was a reason this is the preferred method as opposed to using a static class variable. Is the issue that the reference count would not be fine grained enough i.e. if i had two `shared_ptr<int>`'s pointing to two different things on the heap, they would both be using the same reference count static variable?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue.

Comment: Well yeah. Each thing needs its own reference count otherwise the reference count is useless.

Comment: Thanks! I know it's a dumb question but had to be sure.